# Sooo..... how are we doing with this whole "moderator revolt" thing?

Tags: discussion

I met by chance one of the original/foundational SO developers at a bar the other day.  He told me it had been a long day and he needed a beer.  After talking I hopped on 'meta' later and saw the whole uproar over things related to moderators, community, etc. and understood a bit more about why it had been a long day for him.

What I saw was a lot of conflict about how SO is percieved as treating moderators.  But in here it seems pretty quiet on the topic.

Does the topic at hand bother anyone?   Maybe better as a chat topic, but meta is full of "chat topic" posts so I'm using it as my example a bit.

PS
If you don't know what I'm talking about, then that's fine - in fact it's a sign that the conflict going on in https://meta.stackexchange.com/ has indeed not showed up on your radar.

Comment: Are you looking for yes, no / taking a poll, or are you prompting for longer form discussion?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for mod's thoughts about this?

Comment: Like the tag says, discussion.  And I’d like to hear any opinion.

Comment: @TomTsagk As per the [mod agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), mods are volunteers, not employees, thus [unpaid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169210/228147).

Answer (score 3):

I'm concerned about it.

I come here to share what I know, learn things I don't know and to get some social interaction. I have strong concerns about doing that in a system where people are treated poorly. It's made me more introspective about my participation.

I'm also unsure what the relative lack of reaction here means. I could see that number of different ways.

The recent [response by David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) (Stack Overflow’s CTO) is promising; time will tell how those promises are kept.

Comment: I guess their commitment should be seen as "Look team, this is our focus now so let's not mess this up more". I found it "bold" and risky to give a timeline.

Comment: Yeah. That seems like a tight turn around between getting mod feedback & public announcement. Especially given the spectrum of reactions to date.

Comment: And in the retrospective this post by David lead pretty much to nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm only active on GDSE at the moment. I'm a 12k member of SO, but I don't go there very often at the moment.

The impact of said events has been pretty minimal around here, and I think that's because our mod team and community are very strong. :)